# Make Request to Auth0 api from react native app

Tags: react-native, auth0

I have a  react native app authenticated with Auth0.

I have an API that uses react native.

When a user signs in, i take the `accessToken` that is given for that user, and I make request to the API with the `accessToken` set as the authorization header.

I do so like this:

```
const requestHeader = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        }
    }

axios.post(API_BASE + '/api/example/', requestHeader)
```

The `accessToken` is something short like this: `aBQdd0kOvb1pNj-9XDj_C6bKWkMg9D_q`

When I try to validate the request with the API, I get this error:

```
UnauthorizedError: jwt malformed
```

I know i'm getting this error because the access token isn't a JWT.

I'm validating in the API like this:

```
exports.checkJwt = jwt({
    secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: 'https://dev-0p1doq9r.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json'
  }),
  audience: 'ddasdsfasdfasd',
  issuer: 'safsdfasdfasdfafsdf',
  algorithms: ['RS256']
});
```

I know that `accessToken` needs to be transformed into a JWT on the client, BUT HOW? I have not found any documentation for this; I have also not found what other properties need to be included in the JWT for validation.

Comment: JWT Token includes the user name,issue and expiration time, scope of the access etc. 
Have your reviewed the documentation link for generating the tokens for Auth0 : https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/access-tokens/get-access-tokens